# Для запуска активити требуется тема AppCompat, но TabLayout хочет Theme.MaterialComponents, а с ней работает всё криво

Tags: java, android, стилизация

### Описание проблемы и логи ошибок

Здравствуйте! У меня какая-то очень запутанная проблема, я вообще не имею представления о том, как её решить. Помогите пожалуйста, а то я с этими стилями и темами уже замаялся

В моём приложении изначально стояла тема `Theme.Material3.Dark`, Android Studio выдавало в редакторе макетов ошибку `Failed to instantitate one or more classes`, но у меня на телефоне всё работало замечательно. Но оказалось, что так шло не на всех устройствах. На многих писало ошибку:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{special.hometask.viewer/special.hometask.viewer.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

Если я установлю тему `Theme.AppCompat`, то ошибка `Failed to instantiate...` пропадёт, но тогда при запуске на телефоне будет

```
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #89: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:658)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:801)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:874)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:835)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:877)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:835)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                                                                                                        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:775)
                                                                                                        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:197)
                                                                                                        at special.hometask.viewer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:198)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7458)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7448)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1286)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3614)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:86)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2199)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:112)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:247)
2023-10-23 08:02:35.934 31155-31155 AndroidRuntime          special.hometask.viewer              E      at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkMaterialTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:216)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkCompatibleTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:144)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.obtainStyledAttributes(ThemeEnforcement.java:76)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.<init>(TabLayout.java:536)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.<init>(TabLayout.java:516)
```

Из ошибки видно, что нужна `Theme.MaterialComponents`. Ставлю её всё запускается, но... FAB стал круглым, кнопки поменяли свой фон, отображение MaterialSwitch крашит приложение. `Failed to instantiate one or more classes` в этом случае не появляется.

### Разметка, стили и build.gradle

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/chatFab"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/md_primary70"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottomNav"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/chat" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/refreshFab"
        style="?attr/floatingActionButtonSmallStyle"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/md_theme_dark_secondaryContainer"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/chatFab"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:shapeAppearance="@style/ShapeAppearance.Material3.Corner.Medium"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/refresh"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"/>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/newHometaskFab"
        style="?attr/floatingActionButtonSmallStyle"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/md_theme_dark_secondaryContainer"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/refreshFab"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:shapeAppearance="@style/ShapeAppearance.Material3.Corner.Medium"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/plus"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/settingsTabLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottomNav"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/settingsRecycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/home_tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNav"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            style="@style/Widget.App.TabLayout"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/goToCurrentDate"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/nextWeek"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/selectDate">

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/mon" />

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tue" />

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/wed" />

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/thu" />

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/fri" />



        </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/prevWeek"
            style="?attr/materialIconButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="44dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:paddingStart="0dp"
            android:paddingLeft="0dp"
            android:paddingTop="0dp"
            android:paddingEnd="0dp"
            android:paddingRight="0dp"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            app:icon="@drawable/arrow_left"
            app:iconTint="@color/iconColor"
            app:iconGravity="textStart"
            app:iconSize="24dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/selectDate"
            style="?attr/materialIconButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="44dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:paddingStart="0dp"
            android:paddingLeft="0dp"
            android:paddingTop="0dp"
            android:paddingEnd="0dp"
            android:paddingRight="0dp"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            app:icon="@drawable/month"
            app:iconGravity="textStart"
            app:iconSize="24dp"
            app:iconTint="@color/iconColor"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/tabLayout"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/tabLayout"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/prevWeek" />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/goToCurrentDate"
            style="?attr/materialIconButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="44dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/go_to_current_date"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:paddingStart="0dp"
            android:paddingLeft="0dp"
            android:paddingTop="0dp"
            android:paddingEnd="0dp"
            android:paddingRight="0dp"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            app:icon="@drawable/current_date"
            app:iconGravity="textStart"
            app:iconSize="24dp"
            app:iconTint="@color/iconColor"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/tabLayout"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/tabLayout"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/prevWeek" />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/nextWeek"
            style="?attr/materialIconButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="44dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:paddingStart="0dp"
            android:paddingLeft="0dp"
            android:paddingTop="0dp"
            android:paddingEnd="0dp"
            android:paddingRight="0dp"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            app:icon="@drawable/arrow_right"
            app:iconTint="@color/iconColor"
            app:iconGravity="textStart"
            app:iconSize="24dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/prevWeek"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/nextMonth"
            style="?attr/materialIconButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="44dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:paddingStart="0dp"
            android:paddingLeft="0dp"
            android:paddingTop="0dp"
            android:paddingEnd="0dp"
            android:paddingRight="0dp"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            app:icon="@drawable/arrow_right_2"
            app:iconGravity="textStart"
            app:iconSize="24dp"
            app:iconTint="@color/iconColor"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/editHometaskBottomSheet"
            style="?attr/materialIconButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="44dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:paddingStart="0dp"
            android:paddingLeft="0dp"
            android:paddingTop="0dp"
            android:paddingEnd="0dp"
            android:paddingRight="0dp"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            app:icon="@drawable/arrow_left_2"
            app:iconGravity="textStart"
            app:iconSize="24dp"
            app:iconTint="@color/iconColor"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/nextMonth"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/week_info_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"

            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="@dimen/generalText"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tabLayout"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/editHometaskBottomSheet"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/nextWeek"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/weekViewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tabLayout" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNav"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:foregroundGravity="bottom"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:paddingStart="2dp"
        android:paddingEnd="2dp"
        app:itemPaddingBottom="8dp"
        app:itemPaddingTop="8dp"
        app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@style/BottomNavigationView.Active"
        app:itemTextAppearanceInactive="@style/BottomNavigationView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottomnav" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="BottomNavigationView" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption">
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/smallText</item>
        <item name="tabRippleColor">@color/md_primary30</item>
    </style>

    <style name="BottomNavigationView.Active" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption">
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/smallText</item>
        <item name="tabRippleColor">@color/md_primary30</item>
    </style>

    <style name="BottomNav" parent="Widget.Material3.NavigationRailView">
        <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/BottomNavOverlayDefault</item>
        <item name="dynamicColorThemeOverlay">@style/BottomNavOverlay</item>
    </style>

    <style name="BottomNavOverlayDefault" parent="ThemeOverlay.Material3">
        <item name="colorSecondaryContainer">@color/md_primary30</item>
        <item name="itemRippleColor">@color/md_primary30</item>
    </style>

    <style name="BottomNavOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.Material3">
        <item name="colorSecondaryContainer">@color/material_dynamic_primary30</item>
    </style>


    <style name="Widget.App.TabLayout" parent="Widget.Material3.TabLayout">
        <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ThemeOverlay.App.TabLayout</item>
        <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearanceTabs</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TextAppearanceTabs" parent="TextAppearance.Material3.TitleMedium">
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/generalText</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ThemeOverlay.App.TabLayout" parent="">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/md_primary70</item>
        <item name="colorSurface">@color/md_theme_light_onBackground</item>
        <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/md_theme_dark_onBackground</item>
    </style>



    <style name="Snackbar" parent="Widget.Material3.Snackbar">
        <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/SnackbarOverlayDefault</item>
    </style>

    <style name="SnackbarButton" parent="Widget.Material3.Button.TextButton.Snackbar">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/md_theme_light_primary</item>
    </style>

    <style name="SnackbarOverlayDefault" parent="ThemeOverlay.Material3.Snackbar">
        <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/md_theme_light_onSecondaryContainer</item>
        <item name="colorOnSurfaceInverse">@color/md_theme_light_secondaryContainer</item>
    </style>

    <style name="OutlinedTextField" parent="Widget.Material3.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">

        <item name="textInputStyle">@style/Widget.Material3.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox</item>
        <item name="editTextStyle">@style/Widget.Material3.TextInputEditText.OutlinedBox</item>

    </style>

    <style name="WheelPicker">
        <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/WheelPickerOverlayDefault</item>
        <item name="dynamicColorThemeOverlay">@style/WheelPickerOverlay</item>
    </style>

    <style name="WheelPickerOverlayDefault" parent="ThemeOverlay.Material3">
        <item name="wheel_selected_item_text_color">@color/md_primary70</item>
        <item name="wheel_item_text_color">@color/md_theme_dark_onBackground</item>
    </style>

    <style name="WheelPickerOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.Material3">
        <item name="wheel_selected_item_text_color">@color/material_dynamic_primary70</item>
        <item name="wheel_item_text_color">@color/material_dynamic_neutral90</item>
    </style>



    <style name="SegmentedButton" parent="ThemeOverlay.Material3">
        <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/SegmentedButtonOverlay</item>
    </style>

    <style name="SegmentedButtonOverlay" parent="Widget.Material3.Button.OutlinedButton">
        <item name="colorContainer">#00000000</item>
        <item name="color">@color/md_primary30</item>
    </style>

    <style name="SegmentedButton.Selected" parent="Widget.Material3.Button.OutlinedButton">
        <item name="colorContainer">@color/md_primary30</item>
    </style>

    <style name="FAB" parent="Widget.Material3.FloatingActionButton.Primary">
        <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ThemeOverlay.App.FloatingActionButton</item>
    </style>

    <style name="SmallFAB" parent="Widget.Material3.FloatingActionButton.Secondary">
        <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ThemeOverlay.App.FloatingActionButton.Small</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ThemeOverlay.App.FloatingActionButton.Small" parent="Widget.Material3.FloatingActionButton.Secondary">
        <item name="colorContainer">@color/md_theme_dark_secondaryContainer</item>
        <item name="colorOnContainer">@color/md_theme_dark_onSecondaryContainer</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ThemeOverlay.App.FloatingActionButton" parent="">
        <item name="colorContainer">@color/md_primary70</item>
        <item name="colorOnContainer">@color/md_theme_light_onPrimaryContainer</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    namespace 'special.hometask.viewer'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "special.hometask.viewer"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1 
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
}

dependencies {

    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs_nio:2.0.3'
    implementation (files('libs/simplemagic-1.17.jar'))
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.13.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.11.0'
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.3.0'
    implementation (files('libs/WheelPicker-1.1.3.aar'))
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.2'
    implementation'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.16.0'
    implementation 'com.maxkeppeler.sheets:info:2.3.1'
    implementation 'org.kohsuke:github-api:1.316'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему, унаследовав свою тему от `Theme.Material3.Dark.NoActionBar`